# How do I take values from two different HTML textboxes?

Tags: php

I have a problem in PHP when using `$_POST['something'];`.

I have two textboxes in an HTML body like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="style7">
        Data Base username
        <input name="uname" type="text" style="width: 136px" /></div>
</form>

<form method="post">
    <div class="style7">
        Password:<input name="pass" type="password" style="width: 202px" /></div>
</form>
```

I want to take the values from these textboxes so I am doing this:

```
<?php
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    echo $pass;
    echo $uname;
?>
```

When I put a value only at the first textbox it prints only the first. The same happens when I put a value only on the second textbox. But, when I put values in each textbox at the same time and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it prints only the second value.

Is there a way to take the value from two HTML textboxes at the same time using PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put them in the same `<form>`.

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="style7">
        Data Base username
        <input name="uname" type="text" style="width: 136px" />
    </div>
    <div class="style7">
        Password
        <input name="pass" type="password" style="width: 202px" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: When i put them in the same form then when i give values (even seperately) and hit enter nothing happens. It's like the php script isn't there. It just makes a small beep and nothing else happens :/

Comment: Add a submit button and `action="yourscript.php"` to the `<form>` tag